# trouble calling an import class from an action in a plugin before wp_cron executes

Tags: loop, wp-cron, oop

I’m using the wp_crontrol plugin to call an action added in my functions.php file which then calls a function in my plugin file.
WP gets to my function but can’t call the class, I get this error:  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'RSS_Import' not found in xxx

I’m fairly certain that i am calling the class improperly, but I am not sure how to call the class BEFORE the wp_cron calls it.

**functions.php**

`add_action( 'my_hookname', 'my_function_plugin' );`

**plugin_file.php**

functions.php
'add_action( 'my_hookname', 'my_function_plugin' );’

plugin_file.php

```
if ( !defined('WP_LOAD_IMPORTERS') )
return;

// Load Importer API
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/import.php';

if ( !class_exists( 'WP_Importer' ) ) {
 $class_wp_importer = ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-importer.php';
 if ( file_exists( $class_wp_importer ) )
  require_once $class_wp_importer;
}

/**
 * RSS Importer
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Importer
 */

/**
 * RSS Importer
 *
 * Will process a RSS feed for importing posts into WordPress. This is a very
 * limited importer and should only be used as the last resort, when no other
 * importer is available.
 *
 * @since unknown
 */
if ( class_exists( 'WP_Importer' ) ) {
class RSS_Import extends WP_Importer {

……….

function dispatch(){
error_log("In Dispatch", 0);
$this->header();
$this->get_posts();
$this->import_posts();
$this->footer();
}//dispath

function RSS_Import(){

}//rss_import
} //end class rss importer
error_log("im not called at all", 0);
$rss_import = new RSS_Import();
register_importer('rss', __('RSS', 'rss-importer'), __('Import posts from the Berkeley Blogs RSS feed.', 'rss-importer'), array($rss_import, 'dispatch'));

} // class_exists( 'WP_Importer' )





function my_function_plugin() {
$rss_import = new RSS_Import();
register_importer('rss', __('RSS', 'rss-importer'), __('Import posts from the Berkeley Blogs RSS feed.', 'rss-importer'), array($rss_import, 'dispatch'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved my own problem by giving up and using wordpress's fetch_feed function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed

this works well for me because i dont have to worry about timing when calling parameters.